# how to use lsearch in tcl with numeric

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL word. I have a list which js numeric and when I use lsearch for numeric it is not print properly. Could you please help me what's wrong in my  command

```
          set a {12,121,124,21,212}
          lsearch -integer $a 12
```

Expected output : 12
Actual Output : 12,121, 124, 212

Comment: Your a variable when treated as a list has a single element...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understood

Comment: In Tcl, list elements are not separated by commas.

Comment: `llength $a` is 1. Plus `lsearch` returns an index the way you're using it, not the actual value matching element (so with a single element list it can only return -1 or 0)... are you leaving something out?

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't post properly but I was using reading a file and using if condition. I was greping the lines

Answer (score 1):

You've got a list that is separated by commas, whereas Tcl lists (the kind that `lsearch` can search and `lsort` can sort) are separated by spaces. The `split` command can do the conversion for you:

```
set a {12,121,124,21,212}
set theList [split $a ","]
lsearch -integer $theList 12
```

The result of the search is `0`, which is the index of the first item in the list (Tcl uses zero-indexing, like a lot of programming languages).

To get the actual value found (no so useful in this case, but definitely more useful in more complex ones) you'd provide the `-inline` option.

```
lsearch -inline -integer $theList 12
```